# Running PsExec.exe on Remote PC

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a PowerShell script that configures WinRM on our remote servers when ran on the local user's account. However, I need to upload the script to TFS and have each host run the script themselves.

The script checks if WinRM is configured. If it is not, then it checks if the C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe path exists. If the path exists, it needs to configure WinRM using:

```
$configure = (C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\$hostname -s winrm.cmd -q 2> $null)
```

However, the above results in the error

> The term 'C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I know the file is there, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Other examples I've seen use either `psexec` alone or `./PsExec.exe`, but none of those work.

Any advise appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Remove the parentheses as they're unnecessary

Comment: Does `gcm /pstools/psexec` return anything?

Comment: Right, the parentheses is just a style preference, doesn't affect the operation.
`Get-Command -Name c:/pstools/psexec.exe` does return the file information (CommandType: Application - Name: psexec.exe - Version: 2.20.0.0 - Source: C:\pstools\psexec.exe)

Comment: When you say "upload the script to TFS and have each host run the script themselves" - does this mean you're running the script on the TFS server or running it on each host that needs winrm configured on?

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer why `psexec.exe` isn't working (although I suspect it's because the file isn't actually there), you can use `WMI` to enable `WinRM` instead:

```
([wmiclass]"\\$hostname\root\cimv2:win32_process").
    Create('powershell "Enable-PSRemoting -Force -SkipNetworkProfileCheck"')
```

and to restart your service remotely (even though `Enable-PSRemoting` handles this):

```
$svc = [wmi]"\\$hostname\root\cimv2:win32_service.Name='winrm'"
$svc.StopService()
$svc.StartService()
```

Comment: I know the file is there because I put it there yesterday and am currently logged in to that remote PC looking at it haha. I was unaware of being able to do the same thing in WMI, though, I will give that a shot. The only other command PsExec is used for in the script is to restart WinRM, which I am assuming WMI can do that as well then?

Comment: @Skyler Yup, `$svc = [wmi]"\\$hostname\root\cimv2:win32_service.Name='winrm'"; $svc.StopService(); $svc.StartService()`  but `Enable-PSRemoting` does this for you anyways.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @TheIncorrigible1, I appreciate your help. The restart is working, but the enable function is returning `Cannot convert value \\<hostname>\root\cimv2:win32_process" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: path"`. Doing some searching for a resolution.

Comment: @Skyler I've updated my answer.  I used the wrong typecast

Comment: thanks, I'll do some testing with it. We have several powershell scripts running in TFS, so this script will run first to make sure WinRM is enabled first or all subsequent scripts will fail.